# simplifying the coefficient of variation

Tags: probability, variance

The coefficient of variation $c$ is defined as the ratio of the standard deviation to the mean, and so,

$c^2=\frac{(\mathbb{E}[(x-\mu)^2])}{(\mathbb{E}[\mu])^2}$

I am given the result that

$c^2=\frac{\mathbb{E}[x^2]}{(\mathbb{E}[\mu])^2}-1$

But what has happened to the term $\mathbb{E}[-2x\mu]$ which would (?) come from $(x-\mu)^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mu = \mathbb{E}[x]$ is a constant and using the linearity of expectation, you get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[(x-\mu)^2] & = \mathbb{E}[x^2 - 2\mu x + \mu^2] \\
& = \mathbb{E}[x^2] - \mathbb{E}[2\mu x] + \mathbb{E}[\mu^2] \\
& = \mathbb{E}[x^2] - 2\mu\mathbb{E}[x] + \mu^2 \\
& = \mathbb{E}[x^2] - 2\mu(\mu) + \mu^2 \\
& = \mathbb{E}[x^2] - \mu^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, using that $\mathbb{E}[\mu] = \mu$, the original equation becomes

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
c^2 & = \frac{\mathbb{E}[(x-\mu)^2]}{(\mathbb{E}[\mu])^2} \\
& = \frac{\mathbb{E}[x^2] - \mu^2}{(\mathbb{E}[\mu])^2} \\
& = \frac{\mathbb{E}[x^2]}{(\mathbb{E}[\mu])^2} - \frac{\mu^2}{(\mathbb{E}[\mu])^2} \\
& = \frac{\mathbb{E}[x^2]}{(\mathbb{E}[\mu])^2} - 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Comment: You are right about the errant squaring - but a mistake from multiple $\LaTeX$ terms rather than a misunderstanding of the definition. I will fix.

Comment: @adrianmcmenamin Thanks for the clarification, and making that fix to your question. Since my solution's initial paragraph no longer applied, I have removed it.